# output words of a title in a string in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am attempting to create a function in powershell that accepts a title e.g(star wars) and outputs it capitilized (Star Wars). Also accepts a switch -allcaps which converts it all to upper case. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to output the second word in the title for example this was my last attempt(See Below).

PS C:\Windows\system32> TitleGen star wars

Star

Some of my peers have suggested implementing a array but every time I do the function outputs the second word and leaves me back at square one, so either i'm doing it wrong or i'm wrong altogether . I'm pretty new to powershell i'm not asking for the answer but rather a push in the right direction

Thanks

PS C:\Windows\system32> TitleGen star wars
Star

```
function TitleGen([switch]$allcaps,[string]$text)
{
    if($allcaps)
    {
        $text.ToUpper()
    }
    else
    {
        $pword=$text

        $pword.substring(0,1).ToUpper()+$pword.substring(1).ToLower() 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ToTitleCase() method?

```
$SayWhat = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$SayWhat.ToTitleCase("star war")
```

Comment: @R9003 Please mark this as answered, if this has answered your question. Thanks.